# How do CS careers progress? What's the end goal?

Tags: software-industry, careers, tech-industry

As the question states: How do CS careers progress? What's the end goal?

I know this is a vague question, but is there anything past management? What's the end goal? Do you completely stop working with the engineers? How does the career usually progress?

As in, say you enter a company as a Jr. Engineer creating or maintaining systems. Then, you are promoted to Sr. Engineer, then Supervisor or Team Lead. What happens after that? Do you stay there? Are you promoted to higher levels of management, where you manage managers?

I'm in college right now studying CS and I'm trying to pick a concentration, but I don't know what I should be looking for past stability.

Comment: As a person in her 60's, the end goal is retirement! In answer to your questions, the end goal is your choice. Some people want to be senior managers, some want to code their entire career, some people become specialists, some become very highly sought after international expert consultants, some change careers enitrely (as I have done at least six times).  You will most likely change your mind multiple times between now and when you are old enough to retire. Don't sweat it right now.

Comment: All the companies I've worked for had parallel management and technical tracks.

Comment: The end goal is whatever you want it to be. You shouldn't be letting other people decide where your career goes.

Comment: I understand that you get to choose, but I was just wondering what the basic track is. Say, if I were to work for a software company as anything regarding programming whether heavy or light, what would my prospects be 10 years down the line? I have a few friends whose parents work in IT in roles that I described, and 15 years down the line, they both make around the same amount but they do vastly different things. Both kept their heads down and just enjoyed the 9-5 while being promoted. Neither necessarily aspired to anything, but climbing the ladder. Does anyone have experience in that?

Comment: I'm just trying to get a straight answer because I don't want to own a company or do anything flashy, I just want to enjoy my job, but when I think about it I have no idea what that ladder looks like aside from, programmer and manager. In other fields, like Mech. Engineers or Chemical Engineers it's a lot more clear what the end goal looks like. You end up managing teams in different projects. Is it the same in general in the IT field? Is it all consulting until you feel like doing something different?

Comment: no one can see ten years into the future, particularly in the fastest changing industry in history, I'm an old man, the changes I have seen since my first Commodore 64 stagger the mind when I look back.

Answer (score 5):

The end goal is usually to become a gazillionaire, however this changes over time quite often, and usually people settle for a comfortable retirement.

Comment: Don't forget to have fun on the way to the comfortable retirement.